# How to access arrays within arrays using Ruby's Symbol#to_proc?

Tags: ruby

How do you write the following using the `Symbol#to_proc` syntax?

```
[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]].map { |r| r[0] }
```

This gives an error that the number of arguments is wrong. But I do not know where to give the index argument.

```
[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]].map &:[]  # Where to put the index 0 ?
```

I prefer the first form, and I just want to know how to do it using `&:`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. You can pass only methods without parameters that way. In your case you need to suply `0` as a parameter, which you can only using block syntax.

On the other hand, you can achieve the same using `first` method:

```
[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]].map(&:first)
```

edit:

Both Joerg's and tokland's answers inspired me to experiment a little bit. You *can* actually do something like this:

```
arr = [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]]
arr.each_with_object(0).map(&:[])
#=> [:a, :b, :c]
arr.each_with_object(1).map(&:[])
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Symbol#to_proc` takes the first argument to be the receiver and passes on any extra arguments it receives to the method, but in this case it gets passed only one argument, because `Enumerable#map` only passes the element as the only argument.

However, if that only argument happens to be an `Array`, then we can use the destructuring bind feature of block argument binding! So, we can simply use `Enumerable#zip` to zip together our elements with an infinite list of `0`s! This, of course, requires that we use something which has block argument binding semantics, i.e. either a block proper:

```
[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]].zip([0].cycle).map {|el, i| el[i]}
```

or a non-lambda `Proc`

```
f = proc {|a, i| a[i] }

[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]].zip([0].cycle).map(&f)
```

It does, however, not work with `Method`s or lambdas, because those don't have block argument binding semantics, they have method argument binding semantics, thus they don't perform automatic destructuring. `Symbol#to_proc`, of course, does a message send, thus ending up invoking a method and not a non-lambda `Proc` or a block. That's why this won't work with `Symbol#to_proc`.

Comment: örg, can you please take a look at the added part of my answer and try to explain why `each_with_object(0)` combined with `map(&:[])` works, and `zip([0].cycle)` doesn't? I see that the former returns Enumerator, and the latter Array, but I can't see why that matters later when `map` calls `[]`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer:

1. Write your own smart `Array#to_proc`: `array.map(&[:[], 0])`. Pretty ugly in this particular case.
2. Use Facets [map_send](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html#map-send-method):

`array.map_send(:[], 0)`

(and 3: as Mladen pointed out: `array.map(&:first)`, but if you want another index you can't)

Comment: Well, ActiveSupport also has `Array#second`, `Array#third`, `Array#fourth`, `Array#fifth` and `Array#fourty_two`, but since there's an infinite number of possible indices, this might get unwieldy after a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely overkill, but for the sake of completeness: you *could* write your own method like

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    ->(x) { x[first] }
  end
end
```

and use it like so:

```
[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]].map(&[0])
```

You can read more about this in my blog post ["Array#to_proc for hash access"](http://thepugautomatic.com/2014/11/array-to-proc-for-hash-access/).